# FLUTTER: How to get widgets to flow on top while the keyboard appears?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to get widgets to flow on top while the keyboard appears, and here's the widget I have:

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: Stack(
        children: [
            Image.network('url'),
            Column(
                children: [
                Text('Some text'),
                SizedBox(height: 11),
                Text('Some text'),
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
)
```

**The result I want is to let the background image stays the same, so it stays under the keyboard, but while letting the column flow on top of the keyboard, so it will change its location as the keyboard showing and dismissing.**

At rest:
[image]

After keyboard showed:
[image]

Comment: Try to put `Container` as the root widget and then `SingleChildScrollView` with another `Container` which has your `Column`.
I had something similar and this worked, but not sure if that helps in your case.

Comment: @zpouip, it only aligns the Column on the top of the screen, but does not move as the keyboard shows and dismisses. But thank you for the reply anyways! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working way:

Surprisingly, by just wrapping the `Column` with a `Padding` widget and give it a padding of `EdgeInsets.only(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)`,
and also adding

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end
```

to the `Column` did the trick! Easy solution~

Answer (score 0):

This is called a custom keyboard.
The plugin `keyboard_actions` can be customized for your needs: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work for me, since I don't know how many 'FocusNodes' I need (**depends on the user**), so I cannot use this package, I'd like to hear from you if you know any other packages that do the same thing! @_@